# Keras Loaded model always train instead of predict

Tags: machine-learning, keras

I am doing a project of deep learning. After training I save the model as h5. In another file, I load the saved model and use the model to predict. However when I run the code in Pycharm, the model starts training again. I restart my laptop and run again but the same thing still appears. Is pycharm running on wrong file?

```
model.save('model_10000.h5')
```

Then in another file

```
    model = load_model('model_10000.h5')
    model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
                  optimizer='adam',
                  metrics=['accuracy'])
    # predict for test set
    pred = model.predict(testX)
```

this is what i got
[image]

Comment: Try using pycharm's debugger to see what code is being run

Comment: Just an FYI you do not need to compile the model

Comment: To evaluate on test set, evaluate() is used.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to compile your saved model, maybe that has something to do with it.

```py
model.save('model_10000.h5')
model = load_model('model_10000.h5')
pred = model.predict(testX)
```

Check this for more detail: https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/save_and_load

Comment: I found what caused the problem. The reason is that I include a file; that prepare_data and train the model, into the test file. The reason I include it is because I call the prepare_data function, but model.fit is outside (not in any functions) , so it automatically train my model again and again.

Answer (score 0):

You need not re-compile the model. your saved model is always compiled and when you load it back, it always return the compiled model [(refer Keras FAQ)](https://keras.io/getting-started/faq/#how-can-i-save-a-keras-model).

So, just remove the `model.compile` step and you will be good to go.